# Question on Theorem 2.2.13 in Partial Differential Equations by Evans

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function

I'm working through the section on Laplace's Equation in Partial Differential Equations by Evans.  I'm having trouble following a step in Evans's proof of the symmetry of Green's function (Theorem 2.2.13 on page 35). The statement of the theorem is as follows:
For all $x,y \space \epsilon \space U$ with $x \not = y$ we have $$ G(y,x)=G(x,y)$$ The function $G$ is Green's function which is defined as $G(x,y) = \Phi(y-x)-\phi^x(y) $ where $\Phi $ is the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation and $\phi^x(y)$ is constructed such that $\Delta \phi^x = 0 $ in $U$ and $\phi^x = \Phi(y-x)$ on $\partial U $.   He begins the proof by defining $v(z) := G(x,z)$ for a fixed $x$ and $ w(z) := G(y,z) $ for a fixed $y$.

In the middle of the proof, he states that $v(z) = \Phi(z-x) - \phi^x(z)$, where $\phi^x$ is smooth in $U$ and that therefore $$(*) \space \space\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}wdS = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \nu}(x-z)w(z)dS = w(x)$$ Here, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} = \nabla v \cdot \nu $ where $\nu$ is the outward oriented unit normal vector. It is here that I get confused.  I understand the second equality in (*) but I don't understand how the first equality works.  By my understanding, $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} = \nabla v \cdot \nu = \nabla \Phi(y-x) \cdot \nu - \nabla \phi^x \cdot \nu$$ and I don't understand what happens to the $\nabla \phi^x$.  Why isn't it this instead?: $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}wdS = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}[\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \nu}(x-z)-\frac{\partial \phi^x}{\partial \nu}]w(z)dS$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, as you stated, $\phi^x$ is smooth, and you're integrating it against $w$, which is locally bounded there, over a set of decreasing size ($~\epsilon^{n - 1}$). So that part goes to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I'm beginning to understand.  Because $\phi^x$ is smooth, its derivatives are continuous, and since $\partial B(x,\varepsilon)$ is compact, the derivatives of $\phi^x$ are bounded on $\partial B(x,\varepsilon)$.  Therefore, $\nabla \phi^x \cdot \nu$ is bounded and since w is bounded, the whole integrand is bounded and so $\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)} \frac{\partial \phi^x}{\partial \nu}w(z)dS \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.  Is that where the smoothness of $\phi^x$ comes in?